# Delta Epsilon proof of discontinuity example

Tags: epsilon-delta, continuity

The function is:
$\ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{7}{100}x^2-\frac{3}{5}, & x\le 1 \\\\
\frac{100x^2-137x+37}{100(x-1)}, & x > 1
\end{cases}$

For $x_0=1$ find an $\varepsilon$>0 such that for every $\delta$>0 is true that: 
for   $|x-1|$<$\delta$ $ \Rightarrow$ $|f(x)-f(1)|>$ $\varepsilon$.

My questions are 1) Which of the two possible options for $f(x)$ do we use in the $|f(x)-f(1)|>$ $\varepsilon$ and why?? $\\$ and 2) How do we find epsilon?

Just for a reference the answer given is $\varepsilon$=$\frac{3}{100}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: "For $x=1$" doesn't make sense.  Did you mean "for $x>1"?$

Comment: 'Drawing' the function may help. Take an $\epsilon $ nhd of $f (1) $ small enough, ie so that it does not contain points $f (x)$ , for $x>1$